# Saving Related List Field in VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've fumbled my way through the visualforce page below and I'm wondering how I can get the user input to save.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c">            
<!--<div style="width:700px">-->
<apex:form>
<table style = "width:100%; font-size:12px; ">
<tr>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:left; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Technician: {!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Employee_Name__r.Name}
</td>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Inventory Transfer Sheet: {!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Name}
</td>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:right; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    <apex:outputText value="Date: {0, date, MMM/dd/yyyy}" >
        <apex:param value="{!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Date__c}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:left; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Account: {!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Account__r.Name}
</td>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    <apex:outputText value="Work Order: {!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Work_Order__r.Banner_Number__c}" escape="false"/>
</td>
<td style = "width:33%; text-align:right; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Truck: {!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Truck__c}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table style = "width:100%; font-size:12px; ">
<tr>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Item:
</td>
<td style = "width:40%; text-align:left; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Description:
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Unit:
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Qty Taken:
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:bold;">
    Qty Used:
</td>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c.Inventory_Transfer_Lines__r}" var="lineItems">
<tr>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:normal;">
    {!lineItems.Item__r.Name}
</td>
<td style = "width:40%; text-align:left; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:normal;">
    {!lineItems.Description__c}
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:normal;">
    {!lineItems.Unit_of_Measurement__c}
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:normal;">
    {!lineItems.Qty_Taken__c}
</td>
<td style = "width:15%; text-align:center; font-family:SansSerif; font-weight:normal;">
    <apex:inputField value="{!lineItems.Qty_Used__c}"/>
</td>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
<apex:commandButton  action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
</apex:form>
<!--</div>-->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: the standard controller won't save relatedlist items; you'll need a controller extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save parent/child objects, you need some Apex (or JavaScript). Here's one possible approach:

```
<apex:page extensions="InventoryTransferSheetController" lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c">
```

...

```
<apex:commandButton  action="{!saveChildren}" value="Save"/>
```

Add an Apex class:

```
public inherited sharing InventoryTransferSheetController {
  Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c record;
  public InventoryTransferSheetController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    record = (Inventory_Transfer_Sheet__c)controller.getRecord();
  }
  public void saveChildren() {
    update record.Inventory_Transfer_Lines__r;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will I need a test class to go alongside the new class?

Comment: @Kylan Yes, it'll need a unit test. Fortunately, should only be maybe 20-30 lines of code, though.

Comment: Just a quick question, would there be any way the {!saveChildren} action could direct the user back to the original record like the standard {!save} action does?

Comment: @Kylan Yes: `public PageReference saveChildren() {
    update record.Inventory_Transfer_Lines__r;
    return new ApexPages.StandardController(record).view();
  }`